# How does this asynchronous call work in my example

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback

I learn Java and wonder if the `item` in this code line:

```
useResult(result, item);
```

Will be overrwritten by the next call coming from the

```
doItem(item);
```

Here´s the eaxmple:

```
public void doSomeStuff() {
        //  List with 100 items
        for (Item item : list) {
            doItem(item);
        }
    }

    private void doItem(final Item item) {
        someAsyncCall(item, new SomeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Result result) {
                useResult(result, item);
            }
        });
    }
```

the `SomeCallback()` happens some time in the future and it´s another thread

I mean will the `useResult(result, item);` `item` be the same when callback return?

Please advice what happens here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but `useResult` will be called 100 times (assuming all succeed), with each `item` corresponding to its `result`, but not necessarily in the same order as the original list had them.

Comment: but what if `onSuccess` returns when only 50 call has been made, will the `item` be the the same still, as when the Callback was called. Thanks trying to get my head around this

Comment: `doItem` gets called 100 times. `item` is a parameter (local variable). Every call gets its own version. The closure you create with `new SomeCallback` captures the version it needs (and you create 100 of those closures/anonymous objects/callbacks, each independent from each-other). It will not be affected ("overwritten") by the next call.

Comment: What you need to look out for is mutable state in `Item`. If you do `item.setSomething(newValue)` from the callback this may need some thread synchronization. Try to avoid that.

Comment: The `someAsyncCall` is sending the `item` to this ` BackgroundExecutorService` , what if the `item` when it gets enqueue to this services there´s a call to `doItem` before the Thread has kicked of, I know a Thread has it´s own stack/heap to protect variables

Comment: If you submit a task to the ExecutorService it will execute it at some point later. Since the code you submitted (a Runnable or Callable) has a reference to everything it needs, it will not be garbage-collected even when the main thread moves on, if that is what you are worried about. In general, you don't have to worry about "invalid pointers" in Java. No memory that is still needed will be freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean will the `useResult(result, item);` item be the same when callback return?

Of course it will, what would the utility of that be otherwise?

What you are doing is creating 100 **different** `SomeCallback` classes, that will process a different `Item` object.

A skeleton for your `someAsyncCall` may look like this:

```
public static void someAsyncCall(Item i, Callback callback) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> { // new thread
        Result result = computeResult(i);
        callback.onSuccess(result, i);
    });
}
```

The point is: `Callback`, at the moment of instantiation, doesn't know anything about the `Item` he will get as parameter. He will only know it, when `Callback::onSuccess` is executed in the future.

So, will `Item i` change (be assigned a new object) ?

No, because it is **effectively** `final` within `someAsyncCall` (the object value is not explicitly changed).

You can't even assign `i = new Item()`, as the compiler will complain about the anonymous function accessing a `non-final` variable.

You could of course create a new `Item` and pass it to the callback

```
Item i2 = new Item();
callback.onSuccess(result, i2);
```

but then it would become one hell of a nasty library...

Nobody forbids you to do `i.setText("bla")` though, unless your `Result` class is `immutable` (the member fields are `final` themselves).

---

**EDIT**

If your questions is how `java` handles object in method parameters, then the answer is: **yes**, they are a just copy of the original instances.

You could try with a simple swap method `void swap(Item i1, Item 12);` and you'll notice the references are effectively swapped only within function, but as soon as you return the objects will point respectively to their original instances.

But it's a copy that reflects the original instance.

Coming back to your example. Imagine your `someAsyncCall` waits 10000 ms before executing the callback.

in your `for loop`, after you call `doItem`, you also do: `item.setText("bla");`.

When you print `item.getName()` within `useResult` you will get `bla`. Even though the text was changed after the async function was called.